# Accessing browser extension in React

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to acces a NFC reader in the browser through react. The vendor provides a browser extensions and example code in static JS and HTML. This works fine.

However, in react, the functions of the extensions are not recognized?
Do I include something in de package.json?

I tried looking on google, but can only find how to create extensions in react, not how to use extensions in react as a web page.

Comment: Sounds like [Use a content script to access the page context variables and functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what the NFC reader and the browser extension?